# Toggling UITableViewCell selectionStyle causes labels on cell to disappear

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom subclass of UITableViewCell.  On my storyboard, it basically has a containerView (UIView *), that has some labels on it, and a UISwitch.  I add a gesture to slide my tableViewCell to the right to show some detail controls underneath the containerView, and then another gesture to slide the original view back.  The animation code looks like this:

```
- (void)showCustomControls:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.containerView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - kTableViewCellSwipedWidth, 0, self.frame.size.width - kTableViewCellSwipedWidth, kOverviewTableViewCellHeight)];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.isReveal = YES;
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }];
}

- (void)hideCustomControls:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.containerView setFrame:CGRectMake(-kTableViewCellBounceWidth, 0, self.frame.size.width, kOverviewTableViewCellHeight)];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
            [self.containerView setFrame:CGRectMake(-kTableViewCellBounceWidth / 2, 0, self.frame.size.width, kOverviewTableViewCellHeight)];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.containerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, kOverviewTableViewCellHeight)];
        }];

        self.isReveal = NO;
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }];
}
```

I noticed if I left the selectionStyle on, with the row open, it looked kind of funny.  So I wanted to turn the selectionstyle off.  So the code in there is to turn on and off the selection style when the row is open or closed.  It works, however the weird thing is, when hideCustomControls gets called, and my original row slides back into place, the labels on the container view all go away.  I have a little edge of the original row that shows, and when that is showing, the labels are there.  But the second that the row slides all the way in place, all the labels disappear.  The UISwitch which is also on the containerView never has problems though.  It is always present.  Is there a reason why this may be happening?  When I remove the selectionStyle code in both methods, this problem goes away.  Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
I put in the correct code to animate using NSLayoutConstraint.  Now the problem is the UIView subclasses I have on the view underneath show through to the top view when my row slides back into place.  Not sure why this happens...

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, autolayout for everything

Comment: Well auto layout will be for everything in the same storyboard -- it's only settable at the storyboard level. Anyway, when using auto layout, you shouldn't be setting any frames, you should be adjusting constraints. I don't know why changing the selection style would do what it's doing, but you should change the position of your subviews with constraints (or turn off auto layout).

Comment: @rdelmar how do you do view animations with auto layout though?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly to apply it to your example, but in general, you make an IBOutlet to a constraint that you want to change, and change its constant value in the animation block, followed by layoutIfNeeded. I would suggest that you watch the WWDC 2012 videos on auto layout (there are 3 of them).

Comment: Here's a tutorial on combining Auto Layout and Core Animation correctly: http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/42362079291/auto-layout-and-core-animation-auto-layout-was